# Refreshing Google chart not refreshing unless I run refresh code three times

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am building a dashboard using google charts.  There are many toggle buttons that will refresh the charts. I've accomplished this but with one problem.  The code that refreshes the charts needs to be run 3 times to refresh correctly.  If I don't run the code 3 times, it will refresh the chart based on data from the previous data query.  For example, if I have region buttons "US" and "Canada" selected, then click "Asia" the chart will only show "US" and "Canada".  Once I un-select "Asia", it will show all three.  And the cycle continues, as if the charts are trailing the data one click behind.  I've shortened up my code below with only one chart.  There is for loop that runs the code 3 times to make the code update the charts properly.
Any idea how I can get the code to work properly without running it 3 times?

```
<html>
<!--Load Style docs-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ToggleButton-Styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Dashboard-Styles.css">
<body>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(buildCharts);

function buildCharts() {
var jsonChartA = $.ajax({
      url: "Charts/getChartA.php",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

 var optionsA = {
      legend: {'position':'top','alignment':'center',maxLines:2},
      title:'Franchise Totals by Year',
      width: 1525, height: 325,
      vAxis: {minValue: 0},
      'chartArea': {'width': '85%', 'height': '70%'},
      };
var dataA = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonChartA);
var chartA = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_divP'));
chartA.draw(dataA,optionsA);
}

function updateJson(){
```

> /*Code to get query variables from buttons...*/
>   /*Send variables to php code*/

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "Database.php?Locations=" + Selected_locations + 
           "&months=" + Months + "&years=" + Years + 
           "&status=" + Status + "&global=" + Global + 
           "&region=" + Regions, true );
xhttp.send();
```

> This is the code that I have to run three times...

```
    for(var x =0; x < 3; x++){                  
    var jsonChartA = $.ajax({
    url: "Charts/getChartA.php",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
    }).responseText;

    var optionsA = {
    legend: {'position':'top','alignment':'center', maxLines:2},
    title:'Monthly Totals by Year',
    width: 1525, height: 325,
    vAxis: {minValue: 0},
    'chartArea': {'width': '85%', 'height': '70%'},
    };
    var dataA = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonChartA);
    var chartA = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_divP'));
    chartA.draw(dataA,optionsA);
    }   
}
    </script>

</head>     
<div class="element6"><div id="chart_divP"></div></div>
</body>     
</html>
```

Comment: Add `cache: false` to your ajax setup?

Comment: to look like this?:
    var jsonChartA = $.ajax({

    url: "Charts/getChartA.php",

    dataType: "json",

    async: false,

    cache: false

    }).responseText;

Comment: I tried the above but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I also tried adding $.ajaxSetup({cache: false}); at the beginning of my function.  Same results.